# Python requests hangs whereas CURL doesn't (same request)

Tags: http, curl, python-requests

I'm getting a permanent hang when trying to read a response using requests to access a particular site, most likely due to blocking of some sort. What I'm unsure about is how CURL, which is successfully receiving a response, is different to my Python get request which never receives any response.

Note: the curl command is expected to return an error as i'm not sending required info like cookies
curl:

```
curl 'https://www.yellowpages.com.au/search/listings?clue=Programmer&locationClue=All+States&pageNumber=3&referredBy=UNKNOWN&&eventType=pagination' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0'
```

## successfully gets response

Python:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.yellowpages.com.au/search/listings?clue=Programmer&locationClue=All+States&pageNumber=3&referredBy=UNKNOWN&&eventType=pagination', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0'})
```

## hangs on read forever

Comment: I am also getting a similar error. Are you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with python 3.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.yellowpages.com.au/search/listings?clue=Programmer&locationClue=All+States&pageNumber=3&referredBy=UNKNOWN&&eventType=pagination', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0'})
print(r.headers)
```

Response:

```
{'Cache-Control': 'max-age=86400, public', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Content-Language': 'en-US', 'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=utf-8', 'Server': 'Apache-Coyote/1.1', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'Content-Length': '8009', 'Date': 'Wed, 19 Feb 2020 06:04:55 GMT', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
```

Comment: I found that it's ip-based rather

Comment: Could you please explain "ip-based"? what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

There maybe subtle differences in the ways requests are made. For example Python requests will automatically add a few headers:

`'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'`

(You can see them by executing: `r.request.headers`)

Whereas Curl will add: `Accept: */*` but not gzip unless you ask for it. But the site in question seems to support gzip so the problem must lie elsewhere.

Suggestion: add a timeout in your request, and catch possible exceptions ie:

```
try:
    r = requests...

except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print (e)
```

Comment: I tried emulating the exact CURL request headers to no avail. It's a read timeout which provides an exception when i give a timeout parameter, so don't think i'd get any useful info from that